# ¿Hay alguna regla para la posición del adverbio en una frase?

Tags: adverbios, orden-de-palabras

Hace unos días, el director de La Vanguardia Màrius Carol terminaba su artículo [El tañer de campanas](http://www.lavanguardia.com/opinion/20170325/421159345216/el-taner-de-campanas.html) con la frase:

> En la Ciudad Eterna deberían *hoy* volver a tañer las campanas.

Al leerlo me sonó un poco raro, así que la verbalicé. Y siguió sonándome postiza la posición del *hoy* entre *deberían* y *volver*.

En inglés se hace mucho hincapié en el orden los adverbios. En español no conozco reglas específicas, pues en general la posición de las palabras tiende a usarse para enfatizar una parte u otra. Por ejemplo, no tiene la misma connotación *le gusta mucho ese juego* que *mucho le gusta ese juego*. De esto último se habló en [In Spanish, do time declarations have to follow a specific order?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17009/1674).

Busqué un poco y encontré en Lingolía un artículo sobre la [posición de los adverbios](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/adverbios/posicion):

> Normalmente, el adverbio no [debe] aparecer entre el verbo auxiliar y el verbo principal.
>
> Ejemplo:
>   - Ella había probado suficientemente la raqueta.<sub>(y no: Ella había suficientemente probado la raqueta.)</sub>

Entonces, ¿aplica esta regla a la frase que menciono al principio de la pregunta? ¿Sería más correcto decir lo siguiente? ¿Mantendría su sentido?

> En la Ciudad Eterna *hoy* deberían volver a tañer las campanas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La intercalación de adverbios y perífrasis adverbiales en medio de perífrasis verbales y tiempos compuestos se trata en la gramática en los [epígrafes 28.5e y siguientes](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bepKRdTFvzzDsYsb). Transcribo a continuación algunos extractos:

> Las perífrasis verbales coinciden con los tiempos compuestos en admitir ciertos adverbios entre auxiliar y auxiliado, aunque estos últimos suelen estar [...] más limitados en esta pauta sintáctica. Resultan más naturales [...] oraciones como *Las discusiones solían invariablemente ser infructuosas* que la variante con tiempo compuesto: *...habían invariablemente sido infructuosas.*
>
> La interpolación de adverbios en los tiempos compuestos es poco frecuente en la lengua oral contemporánea. En la escrita la favorecen especialmente ciertos grupos de adverbios. Destacan, entre ellos, los aspectuales, sobre todo *ya, todavía* y -en menor medida- *gradualmente, poco a poco, por completo* y otros similares: [...] *Mi padre me había **ya** enseñado con su ejemplo que la muerte es solamente un primer paso en nuestro viaje sin retorno hacia el silencio*, [...]; *Ha sido verdaderamente accidental que el término se haya **gradualmente** restringido para cierta clase concreta de asociaciones*.
>
> Los adverbios mencionados y otros semejantes pueden interpolarse igualmente entre los componentes de algunas perífrasis verbales, como "*ir* + gerundio" (*Iban **progresivamente** disminuyendo*), "*venir* + gerundio" (*Vienen **ya** superando los dos mil dólares*) y otras [...]: *No voy **ahora** a insistir sobre la cuestión*; [...]; *Las tropas chinas irían **progresivamente** ocupando todas las regiones del país*; [...]; *Edmundo pasó varias tardes en su piso franco hojeando revistas musicales y oyendo la radio para poder **después** dar alguna sugerencia útil y así hacerse valer*; *Volvía **de nuevo** a jugar la única carta que en mi situación podía jugar, la de quitarles importancia a las cosas*; *Podía **quizás** ser impura, pero no tenía nada de extraña*.
>
> Las perífrasis verbales aceptan las interpolaciones de palabras negativas, como en *No pudo ni siquiera llamarla*; *Nadie iría nunca a pensar algo así* [...].
>
> Los tiempos compuestos admiten los adverbios *ni siquiera* y *ni* ante el participio [...], con la posible excepción de las formas monosilábicas [...] (*No has ni probado la ensalada*). Admiten también los adverbios *nunca* y *tampoco* (*Nadie lo había tampoco previsto*) [...].

Así pues, en el caso de tu ejemplo, al tratarse de una perífrasis verbal, se otorga a estas construcciones una cierta flexibilidad a la hora de intercalar elementos adverbiales, más que si fuese un tiempo compuesto. Por lo tanto, nada indica que el ejemplo sea incorrecto. Tal vez suene raro por infrecuente, pero nada más.

Comment: Fantástico. Efectivamente suena raro (al menos a mí), es interesante saber que sí es correcto. Reafinaré el oído para que me suene mejor.